# How can i make ZSH use the latest git version?

Tags: macos, git, path, zsh

I am using ZSH with oh-my-zsh on OS X.

Today I used hombrew to update to the latest version of git (1.8.something).

However, if I run

```
➜  ~  git --version
git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)
```

I see that still an older version is used. On bash everything works fine and the latest version of git is called.

Since I am new to ZSH, any advice on how to set up ZSH to use the "new" git is appreciated!

Best,

Tobi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the PATH modification didn't instantly work, you need to realize that with zsh you need to type "rehash" for zsh to recognize there are new executables in the path. Or just log out and back in.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I also tried your method and even rebooted several times, but so far my additions to ~/.zshenv seem to be ignored.

Comment: @tobias.henn What does `echo $PATH` say? Does it completely exclude everything you put in .zshenv? If you set it manually, like `export PATH=/usr/local/whereyourgitis:$PATH`, `rehash`, replacing the path with the path you installed new version of git to, does it then run the correct version?

Comment: FWIW: `rehash` doesn't actually change the binary that gets called when you type e.g. `git`, it just changes what zsh knows about to do auto-completion and whatnot.

Comment: @Dougal That's not true. Zsh hashes the available executables, and this is done again with the rehash command, see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I suppose the times I've thought were it running without the hash table we're actually when it wasn't in the dictionary at all.

Comment: Neither adding `/usr/local/git/bin/git`, the correct path used in bash, nor typing `rehash` afterwards helps. Rebooting and typing `git --version` still shows `git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)`. What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 6):

This means that your `$PATH` variable isn't set up to include the right `git` (and everything else homebrew installs).

Try doing `echo $PATH` from both bash and zsh. You should see at least one difference: the directory where you installed homebrew, probably `/usr/local/bin`. (It'll either not be in there, or be after `/usr/bin`, where the Apple-supplied binary lives.)

To fix it, add a line like

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to your `~/.zshenv`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! It's not working yet, but I now know in which direction I have to go!

Comment: Finally came back to this issue. It worked after I added your above line to my `~/.zshrc` file!

Answer (score 1):

Compare the outputs of `which git` (and the outputs of `echo "$PATH"`) in `bash` and `zsh`.

The directory containing an up-to-date `git` is probably not present in `$PATH` variable for `zsh`, but it is in `bash`. It's likely caused by `$PATH` items being added in your `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_profile` file, which `zsh` doesn't source on startup. If it's so, add the same assignment to `PATH` to your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Well, we gave basically the same answer at the same time :) – except that `.zshenv` is preferable to `.zshrc`, since the latter only runs in interactive shells.